# Unable to symbolicate SwiftUI while profiling app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, profiling, instruments

For quite some time I am trying to symbolicate SwiftUI framework calls in Instruments.

What I am doing:

1. Open Xcode with related project
2. CMD + I
3. Choose Animation Hitches
4. Locate the hitch, and set the inspection range
5. find Main Thread
6. Switch to the profile

I have no problem with this task on my older machine (MBP Mid 2015) running Monterey 12.6.1.
Currently, I am using MPB 2019 with Ventura 13.1.

What I have tried already.

- Right-click the given call -> Locate dSYM (When I try to match dSYM for the profiled app I get the UUID of my app that does not match the UUID for SwiftUI
- Instruments -> Settings -> Symbols and setting the patch for dSYM there (once again no luck there)
- File -> Symbols (Here I check that my app is symbolicated, which it is. Also, I check for the SwiftUI framework which has a little green dot next to its name, so I suppose it is too.

Comment: Any progress? Same issue here.